# VBA Change the text color in MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change the font color from MsgBox

To understand what I want, I chose this exemple:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim results As String


a = InputBox("Enter your first value:")
b = InputBox("Enter your second value:")
c = InputBox("Enter your third value:")

d = a - b + c

If d = 0 Then
    results = "Correct"
    MsgBox "Your results is: " & results 
Else
    results = "Incorrect"
    MsgBox " Your Results is: " & results 
End If
```

The "Correct" text I want to be in green when it appears in `MsgBox`; the "Incorrect" text I want to be in red when it appears in `MsgBox`

I hope what I have requested is possible.

Comment: You cannot customize a message box in this way. You'll have to create a "custom message box" using a userform. Then you can do what you want (including different font-colors and background colors)..

Comment: I understand. Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Ralph suggests, it'd be better to display your message in a `UserForm` where you'd have easy control over the text characteristics.

However, it is possible to change the colour of your MessageBox text, using the system color API's. As the MessageBox is a Window, you can alter the colour parameters of it (not just text, but various others too).

You'd want to ensure that you reset the original values immediately afterwards of course otherwise all of your windows will display in the modified colours.

The below code will automatically detect 32-bit and 64-bit systems and should work on both equally well:

```
Option Explicit

#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetSysColors Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal nChanges As Long, lpSysColor As Long, lpColorValues As Long) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetSysColor Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SetSysColors Lib "user32" _
        (ByVal nChanges As Long, lpSysColor As Long, lpColorValues As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Const COLOR_WINDOWTEXT As Long = 8
Private Const CHANGE_INDEX As Long = 1

Public Sub RunMe()
   Dim defaultColour As Long

   'Store the default system colour
   defaultColour = GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT)

   'Set system colour to red
   SetSysColors CHANGE_INDEX, COLOR_WINDOWTEXT, vbRed
   MsgBox "Incorrect", , "Your result is..."

   'Set system colour to green
   SetSysColors CHANGE_INDEX, COLOR_WINDOWTEXT, vbGreen
   MsgBox "Correct", , "Your result is..."

   'Restore default value
   SetSysColors CHANGE_INDEX, COLOR_WINDOWTEXT, defaultColour

End Sub
```

Comment: *(+1)* from my side for showing how it *could* work. Still, I'd highly recommend not to use this solution but a custom `UserForm` instead. I hope you don't mind that I adjusted your code / solution to work for 32-bit **and** 64-bit. If you do mind, feel free to revert back to the original solution and punish me by down-voting some of my posts on this site.

Comment: @Ralph, thanks, good edit. And yes, I'd definitely go for the userform too. I just can't resist those "is it possible" questions!

Comment: @Ralph, I agree.  Interesting that it's possible but it sounds dangerous.  Any unhandled error and the user is stuck with the color scheme on buttons throughout Windows.

Comment: @ChrisB, yes I agree too. There are 'safer' API options using `SetTextColor` or something similar, but a Userform would certainly be my choice for managing a window.

Comment: I have a question, i want to change the Color of the Window Border and Bordertext. I guess i have to change the Privat Const numbers?
But how? Do you maybe have any resource for this (so i could read about it by myself)?

Comment: @LucaS I have to say, I rather regret submitting this answer, as no developer would seriously consider changing their system windows colours just to change the font colour of a message. The answer should be to create a `UserForm`. However, for reference, you could have a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsyscolors