# Options of message box in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, msgbox

We would like to change the font, color and size of the text displayed in message boxes.

Can/how do you VBA this?

Nothing tried, we are not finding any help in online manuals, including the Microsoft help site.

We would like to make the message box big, bold and loud.

Comment: With a UserForm, you can create your own "message box" with far more robust ability to control font size, style, etc.

Comment: Likewise, you have far more control over button placement, button text, etc.

Comment: There's a reason why you can't modify a messagebox's appearance: it's uniform across all Windows applications and even Windows itself. So users are presented with a common familiar UI widget. The messagebox also honors the user's (Windows) UI settings. So unless there's a real good reason to "go fancy", use the messagebox "as is". If the _information_ you want to present via a messagebox needs a different layout, a user form is better choice in the first place.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Change the text color in MsgBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408720/vba-change-the-text-color-in-msgbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer: You can't.

That's why you can't find anything about it in the official documentation of the [MsgBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function).

A workaround can be to create your own UserForm where you are free in how to style it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a UserForm in your workbook's code module, and configure it with as many Label and CommandButton controls as needed.

[image]

If the label text will be static, you can configure these all through the Properties window in the IDE:

[image]

Labels, Command Buttons, etc., are accessible *Controls* on the UserForm, and can be altered dynamically during runtime if needed, e.g., during the form's `Initialize` or `Activate` or any other event handlers. Controls on the form can even alter other controls, for example you could leverage the command button's `Click` event handler to modify the text associated with `Label1` control, etc.

You can even add (or remove) controls (labels and such) dynamically, too, and fully control their appearance/formatting/etc.