# ShowMsg("You are logged on as Administrator!", False)

Tags: vb.net

how can i put text color in messages box.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can the most that function takes is 
ShowMessage(String, String, MessageBoxButtons) that means text the caption and the buttons in it. My advice it for you to make a form with clolored label in it and use ShowDialog() method. Here is an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: This is the easiest solution to create your own message form (or at least the least code).  You *can* use the WinAPI to do this, but that's tedious too.  [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408720/vba-change-the-text-color-in-msgbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a variety of icons in your message box.

[image]

Perhaps one of these would get your user's attention without having to roll your own.

```
    MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as Administrator!", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
```

It appears that `ShowMsg` is a custom method so, we would have to see the method to be of any additional help.